# Wordpress private posts and Feedburner - do they trigger an email?

Tags: wordpress, rss, private, feedburner

This seems like a simple question but can't find an answer anywhere online.

I have a Wordpress site that, whenever a post gets published, pushes an email out to feedburner subscribers. Very straight forward.

My question is, I need to change some of the posts to privately published so I can test some new stuff and I dont want subscribers to get an email to an empty post.

Can someone lead me to somewhere where it explains what gets pushed and what isnt?
I'm assuming it wont but want to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to change some of the posts to privately published

If that results in the posts not being in the original public 
wordpress feed, then there's no way for feedburner to get them.

So view the wordpress feed in a browser window where you are 
not logged in to your wordpress account.

However, if you've set your Wordpress feed to have eg. 
the 50 latest posts (the maximum), and a post that you make private 
is within the those 50 , don't be surprised when Wordpress then provides 
the 51st post to Feedburner, which may get re-emailed.